# linux + start script under /etc/init.d dependencies with other services

Tags: linux, services, init.d, chkconfig, start-stop-daemon

from some reason the script UPMnT.sh not start at boot

I cheeked everything:

chkconfig is ok
links are ok

but I worry about maybe there are dependencies between other script to this script

can some one explain how my script under **/etc/init.d** have dependencies with other script under **/etc/inid.d** and this is the reason that **UPMnT.sh** not start at boot

second:

How to understand the line - **chkconfig: 345 98 2**

what this line mean and how the numbers are dependent with other services?

```
 # more /etc/init.d/UPMnT.sh
 #!/bin/sh
 #
 # UPMnT   Startup/Shutdown Service Manager shell script
 #
 # chkconfig: 345 98 2




 chkconfig --list | grep -i UPMnT
 UPMnT       0:off    1:off    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Comment: The chkconfig line means run at run levels 3, 4, and 5. Start at priority 98 (near last) and start at priority 2 (near the start).

Comment: Can you run your script manually, i.e. what does _/etc/init.d/UPMnT.sh_ do?

Comment: Lastly, did you run _chkconfig_ _UPMnT.sh_ to enable your service?

Comment: when I run the script manual , then its ok

Comment: yes I run chkconfig on this service and service is enable

Comment: so how to change the numbers in the line in order to run for sure this service?

Comment: So what does `chkconfig UPMnT.sh` show? Or `chkconfig -l UPMnT.sh`?

Comment: see my update , output from chkconfig

Comment: maybe I need to change the priority to high? ( what is the last high number ? )

Comment: I don't grok the name difference between your `chkconfig` output and the name of the script. Is it UPMnT, UPMnT.sh, or UC4SmgrV9? Regardless, it should be running at startup if chkconfig says so. The _priority_ is really about the order in which it is started and stopped. You can look, for example, in /etc/init.d/rc3.d, and you should see something like "SnnUPMnT", where "nn" is a number, like "98". If you look at all the services in that directory in sorted order (i.e. "ls" on that directory), you will see the order of things being started.